# how to Upload Image Using JQuery And Django

Tags: python, jquery, html, django

I'm trying to build a system that allows users to upload images, I'm using Django 2.1 and I follow [this course](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html). I'm using the exact code but it doesn't work, I don't know what is the problem may be js code is not running This is my code

**item_images_creation.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Photos Library - Simple is Better Than Complex{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      .page-header {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'photos/js/progress-bar-upload.js' %}"></script>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">


  <h1 class="page-header">
    Photos
    <small></small>
  </h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Examples</h3>
        </div>
          <a href="{% url 'item:progress_bar_upload' %}" class="list-group-item{% if request.path == '/progress-bar-upload/' %} active{% endif %}">
            Progress Bar Upload
          </a>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
    </button>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
           style="display: none;"
           data-url="{% url 'item:progress_bar_upload' %}"
           data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
  </div>

  <table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Photo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for photo in photos %}
        <tr>
          <td><a href="{{ photo.file.url }}">{{ photo.file.name }}</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/item_image')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

**views.py**

```
class ProgressBarUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'zwwebsite/item_images_creation.html', {'photos': photos_list})

    def post(self, request):
        time.sleep(1)  # You don't need this line. This is just to delay the process so you can see the progress bar testing locally.
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from item.views import ProgressBarUploadView


    app_name = 'item'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('progress-bar-upload/', ProgressBarUploadView.as_view(), name='progress_bar_upload'),
    ]
```

**settings.py**

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
    """STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
        '/static/',
    ]"""

    # upload images
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from item.views import user_authentication
from . import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('authentication.urls')),
    path('', include('stores.urls')),
    path('', include('item.urls')),
    path('', include('search.urls')),
    path('check-login/', user_authentication, name='check-login'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is how my Network tab in browser looks like

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Rnz.png)

there is noting appear in console tab

and that how my command line looks

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU3Xx.png)

Please help me solve this problem

Comment: In the tutorial you're following, they have a script `basic-upload.js` that does the actual work. Is that your `progress-bar-upload.js`? If so where is that?

Comment: And please check in your browser dev tools what's going on. You should check the Network tab to see if any POST request is made, if the url is correct and what the response is. Also you should tell us what you see in the console, any javascript errors? Finally, in your server console (where you `runserver`) what do you see?